# Can I use cv2 or Numpy to Invert this picture?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Can I use cv2 or numpy to turn an image into a negative? Something like below but I need to edit still.

My question is mainly the top bit of code if I can use that to invert the grayscale and black&white both to a negative?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imageread('imagename.jpg')

print(img.dtype)

image_neg = 255 - img

cv2.imshow('negative',image_neg)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#######################################

from images import Image

def invert(image):





def blackAndWhite(image):

    blackPixel = (0, 0, 0)
    whitePixel = (255, 255, 255)
    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (r, g, b) = image.getPixel(x, y)
            average = (r + g + b) // 3
            if average < 128:
                image.setPixel(x, y, blackPixel)
            else:
                image.setPixel(x, y, whitePixel)

def grayscale(image):

    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (r, g, b) = image.getPixel(x, y)
            r = int(r * 0.299)
            g = int(g * 0.587)
            b = int(b * 0.114)
            lum = r + g + b
            image.setPixel(x, y, (lum, lum, lum))

def main():
    filename = input("Enter the image file name: ")
    image = Image(filename)
    #Invert image
    invert(image)
    image.draw()
    #Covert to greyscale, then invert
    """grayscale(image)
    invert(image)
    image.draw()"""
    #Convert to black and white, then invert
    """blackAndWhite(image)
    invert(image)
    image.draw()"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "invert.py", line 14, in <module>
    image_neg = 255 - image
NameError: name 'image' is not defined
```

I changed the code in the beginning to say this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

    image = cv2.imageread('smokey.gif')

    print(image.dtype)

image_neg = 255 - image

cv2.imshow('negative',image_neg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Well I thought this would work but it tells me line - "invertedImage = cv2.bitwise_not(imageToInvert)" has a SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+00A0

I edited my code correctly on here (4 spaces) and I have no clue why it's not showing correctly still.

```
from images import Image

import cv2

def invert(image):
    imageToInvert = cv2.imread(filepath)
    invertedImage = cv2.bitwise_not(imageToInvert)
    cv2.imgwrite("BWimage.png",invertedImage)
    print("inverted image saved")

File_path='smokey.gif'
invert(File_path)
```

Comment: There is a gray colored **Edit** button below the post. The button looks like a label, but you can press it, and edit your code. I don't understand why `image_neg = 255 - img
` is not good enough. When you edit, please add `python` tag, `opencv` tag and `image-processing` tag.

Comment: Thanks @Rotem I have added the tags. I'm surprised it'a not working as well.

Comment: Replace `img = cv2.imageread('imagename.jpg')` with `img = cv2.imread('imagename.jpg')`. What is not working? The first part? The second part? Editing the question?

Comment: Please explain why you say it's not working. What output do you get? `image_neg = 255 - img` does work for 8-bit unsigned images.

Comment: I changed the code but not working still.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you are getting. Maybe something here will help?

Syntax: **cv2.cv.flip(src, flipCode[, dst] )**

Parameters:
src: Input array.
dst: Output array of the same size and type as src.
flip code: A flag to specify how to flip the array; 0 means flipping around the x-axis and positive value (for example, 1) means flipping around y-axis. Negative value (for example, -1) means flipping around both axes.

Return Value: It returns an image.
As found in OpenCV

```
example code:
# Python program to explain cv2.flip() method

# importing cv2
import cv2

# path
path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\geeks14.png'

# Reading an image in default mode
src = cv2.imread(path)

# Window name in which image is displayed
window_name = 'Image'

# Using cv2.flip() method
# Use Flip code 0 to flip vertically
image = cv2.flip(src, 0)

# Displaying the image
cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```